# What is Wrong With This Code? Simple VML Page is Blank

Tags: internet-explorer, vml

Could someone point out what I am missing with this code? The page remains blank despite it being as simple as I can make it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>VML</title>
<style>
v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}
o\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <v:rect style="width:100;height:100;" fillcolor="blue" strokecolor="red"></v:rect>
</body>
</html>
```

The code was take from [garybeene.com](http://www.garybeene.com/3d/3d-vmltut.htm) which has been suggested in other SO questions as a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `display:inline-block` in the `<style>` element and include the CSS unit `px` when setting the width and height. The following revised version of your code works in IE 7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>VML</title>
<style>
v\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);display:inline-block}
o\:* { behavior: url(#default#VML);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <v:rect style="width:100px;height:100px;" fillcolor="blue" strokecolor="red"></v:rect>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference for the `display:inline-block` can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263897(v=vs.85).aspx